# TurtleBot with Cloud Computing

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've got a TurtleBot II running a small crappy netbook and a great Macbook Pro I'm dual booting with Ubuntu to SSH into it to run Rviz remotely for gmapping. It works, it's just really choppy. I'm pretty sure it's because the netbook processor sucks.

Is there a known way in ROS to add a middle layer between the remote computer and the turtlebot that acts as a cloud computing server to speed things up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71299/turtlebot-with-cloud-computing/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please provide a little bit more information about what you want to speed up.  Usually with rviz the limiting issue is the wireless bandwidth due to the highly graphical nature of rviz.  You can add any computing you want onto the robot, upgrade the machine or put another one on board.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-05**:
I want to speed up the frame rate in Rviz over SSH. It's terribly slow.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-05**:
Ahh, you shouldn't run rviz via SSH.  You should run rviz locall on the Macbook Pro and set it to connect to the robot over ROS not SSH.

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-11**:
thanks, that works